# Send parameters and a list in body of POST request WIth resttemplate Exchange

Tags: json, spring, web-services, post, resttemplate

Hi I have to send a POST request with resttemplate.exchange with these parameters

```
{
"tipoPortafoglio": "string",
  "allegatiPratica": [
    {
      "fileName": "string",
      "body": "string",
      "mimeType": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a mapped class of this called

```
Public class CreateRichiesta { 
String tipoPortafoglio
Allegato  allegatiPratica    //<===== Custom type defined as JSON 
//Getter and setters
```

I cannot pass the entity to RestTemplate.Exchange with HashMap because of customtype infact

```
Map<String,String> input = new HashMap<>();
input.put("tipoPortafoglio", request.getTipoPortafoglio());
input.put("allegatiPratica", request.getAllegatiPratica()));
```

getAllegatiPratica is not string type but Allegato type

How can i do??Thx to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpEntity<CreateRichiesta> request = new HttpEntity<>(new CreateRichiesta());
ResponseEntity<CreateRichiestaResponse> responseEntityObj = restTemplate
     .exchange(resourceUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, CreateRichiestaResponse.class);
```

Comment: wonderfull!!! but the last is not CreateRichiesta.class but CreateRichiestaResponse.class , right?

Comment: Correct https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.net.URI-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-